# wordpress.org codebase

Tags: plugins, wordpress.org, svn, customization

Is the codebase that runs wordpress.org publicly available? Specifically, I'm interested in the part that parses the plugins SVN repository to determine the current and past versions of plugins.

I know that I have to look at the tags for each plugin but there are complexities around which tag is marked as the *Stable tag* in the `readme.txt`.

Answer (score 3):

You can try out the `api.wordpress.org`.

Take for example the *secret* `MP6` plugin:

```
http://api.wordpress.org/plugins/info/1.0/mp6.xml
```

The current version is given by:

```
<version type="string">
<![CDATA[ 0.8 ]]>
</version>
```

and it looks like the previous versions are listed in the compatibility tag:

```
<compatibility type="array">
<array key="3.4.1">
<array key="1.0.0">
<integer>100</integer>
<integer>1</integer>
<integer>1</integer>
</array>
<array key="1.0.1">
<integer>100</integer>
<integer>1</integer>
<integer>1</integer>
</array>
<array key="1.0.2">
<integer>100</integer>
<integer>3</integer>
<integer>3</integer>
</array>
</array>
<array key="3.4.2">
<array key="1.0.2">
<integer>100</integer>
<integer>1</integer>
<integer>1</integer>
</array>
<array key="1.0.5">
<integer>100</integer>
<integer>1</integer>
<integer>1</integer>
</array>
</array>
<array key="3.5">
<array key="1.0.5">
<integer>100</integer>
<integer>1</integer>
<integer>1</integer>
</array>
</array>
<array key="3.5.1">
<array key="1.0.6">
<integer>100</integer>
<integer>2</integer>
<integer>2</integer>
</array>
</array>
</compatibility>
```

You can compare it to the `SVN` versions given here:

```
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mp6/developers/
```

You can also get `json` or serialized `php` versions:

```
http://api.wordpress.org/plugins/info/1.0/mp6.json
http://api.wordpress.org/plugins/info/1.0/mp6.php
```

Comment: +1 for introducing me to the API but it's not quite what I need as the version info is missing for [plugins with few ratings](http://api.wordpress.org/plugins/info/1.0/database-sync.xml).

Comment: thanks, but I can see the  `<version type="string"><![CDATA[ 0.2 ]]></version>` for your plugin. Version `0.1` is not checked into the SVN according to http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/database-sync/developers/